# grep empty output file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I made a shell script the purpose of which is to find files that don't contain a particular string, then display the first line that isn't empty or otherwise useless. My script works well in the console, but for some reason when I try to direct the output to a .txt file, it comes out empty.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# takes user input.
echo "Input substance:"
read substance
echo "Listing media without $substance:" 
cd media

# finds names of files that don't feature the substance given, then puts them inside an array.
searchresult=($(grep -L "$substance" *))

# iterates the array and prints the first line of each - contains both the number and the medium name. 
# however, some files start with "Microorganisms" and the actual number and name feature after several empty lines
# the script checks for that occurence - and prints the first line that doesnt match these criteria.

for i in "${searchresult[@]}"
do
grep -m 1 -v  "Microorganisms\|^$" $i
done >> output.txt
```

I've tried moving the `>>output.txt` to right after the `grep` line inside the loop, tried switching `>>` to `>` and `2>&1`, tried using `tee`. No go.

I'm honestly feeling utterly stuck as to what the issue could be. I'm sure there's something I'm missing, but I'm nowhere near good enough with this to notice. I would very much appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** Added files to better illustrate what I'm working with. Sample inputs I tried: `Glucose`, `Yeast extract`, `Agar`. [Link to files [140kB]](https://gofile.io/?c=HqRv2b) - the folder was unzipped beforehand.

The script was given full permissions to execute. I don't think the output is being rewritten because even if I don't iterate and just run a single line of the loop, the file is empty.

Comment: A great way to get unstuck on any programming problem is to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, the problem could be in input, finding files, iterating over files, or searching inside them. A MCVE would narrow that down significantly

Comment: It's working for me.  I also tried `grep -m 1 -v  "Microorganisms\|^$" $i >> output.txt`. That also worked.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you for the tip! I still didn't manage to locate the issue but I added some more information to hopefully make it more clearer.

Comment: Does something simple like `echo 123 >> output.txt` works?

Comment: Can you double check that you're looking at the right output file? It will be in `media/output.txt`. It will not be in the directory where you run the script.

Comment: Consider adding 'set -x' to your script (or launch with bash -x ...) - it will  provide you with information to debug your script

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, that command works without issue.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes, I have the correct file - but thank you for the idea. Made me check ;)

Comment: When I run your script on Linux and enter `Glucose`, I get a `media/output.txt` with 146 lines in it. You're sure there are no errors or unexpected output when you run the script, right?

Comment: what do you get when you issue cmd `cd media; ls -l output.txt`? Good luck.